# Using 2133 ram on mid macbook 2012

Tags: upgrade, memory

To be more specific, i'm thinking on buying [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H33JU3K) ram for my mid 2012 macbook pro. According to [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1807214) post it seems possible to run 2133, though i'm still not sure if it's really running 2133 and would it give better performance rather then 1866? I'm running heavy virtual envs. on my macbook, and my current 8gb ram is way not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically the speed difference between 1866 and 2133 isn't going to make a significant impact on your overall system speed. It's a 266MHz difference but this does not affect overall performance in the same way a 266MHz CPU speed bump would.

You say you are running virtualised environments, so upgrading to 16GB - *whatever* the RAM speed - will have more of an impact than the RAM speed itself.

If you're looking for the maximum performance from your setup you do really need to be running an SSD in addition to the 16GB RAM, if you're not already.